# Opening a link to download a pdf only works with hard reload and dev tools open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pdf, heroku

There are a several factors here (Heroku, Node, expressjs, react) as I'm working with a few technologies newer to me, so I'm not sure what the missing piece is.

I have a react/node app that is working for me in my local dev environment (using create-react-app).

My "/" route returns a list of documents, from which I create a list of links.  When you click on one, it calls a route that returns a PDF.

This works great locally.

I've deployed it to Heroku and get the following behavior:

1. Click on link
2. Instead of opening the PDF, it opens a new tab with the correct URL, but the response is the list of documents instead of the selected PDF.
3. If I do a hard-reload, I get the same thing.
4. If I open dev tools in Chrome, I get the same thing.
5. If I open dev tools AND THEN do a hard-reload, I get the attachment to render!!
6. If I then do a reload again, it reverts back to showing me the list.

In Edge, I don't need to have dev tools open.  Just a hard-reload will render the attachment, but clicking refresh after, brings the list back instead.

Things I've considered: 
+ If it were a caching issue, I would expect subsequent reloads to render the PDF, despite whether the Control key were down or dev tools open.  Both requests are returning 200, although the one that is not working as expected is returning 200 (from ServiceWorker).  The Remote Addresses are also different.

+If it were a routing issue, I wouldn't expect the PDF to ever get rendered properly.

Things I've noticed in hunting this down:
+ The requests are differing

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out.  The rubber duck helped me :-)

If I don't use https, all is working fine.  I'm not sure, however, why dev tools + hard reload allows me to make the request properly.