# pdf only shows up after hard refresh of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to open a pdf in another tab. Upon clicking the link the first time, you are brought to an empty page, but after hard refreshing the page, the pdf displays correctly.

```
const Plot = ({name, pngUri, pdfUri, search, display, onHover}) => {
  return (
    <Card className={cx(plotSty, display ? null : hidden)} onMouseEnter={onHover}>
      <a href={pdfUri} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>
        <CardHeader>{hlSearch(name, search)}</CardHeader>
        <CardImg src={pngUri} />
      </a>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I did notice that when the new tab first loads, it tries run the main css and js files for the main webpages as well as just the pdf, and those show 404 errors (first image below). The "type" under inspect element > network shows html. While after a hard reload, only the pdf is run (second image below). The "type" here is pdf.
[image: before hard reload]

[image: after hard reload]

Anyone know what's going on here?

I found this that might be related but I am not sure how I would apply to my situation [Opening a link to download a pdf only works with hard reload and dev tools open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482452/opening-a-link-to-download-a-pdf-only-works-with-hard-reload-and-dev-tools-open)

Answer (score -3):

I was experiencing a similar issue, where after my first download of a .pdf and/or .xlsx all others were seemingly blocked, but was getting no errors server side or in the front end. Turned out it was a Chrome setting. It thought that the site was trying to maliciously flood me with multiple downloads and blocking them, turning this off restored expected behavior

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).